# Order by unity of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with same columns, named 't1' and 't2' .

t1 is always bigger than t2. I need to order 't1' by unity of 't1' and 't2'

here is an example

t1:

```
dcDay    dcTime    dcCount
===========================
  0        8          1
  0        10         1
  1        8          2
  2        8          2
```

t2:

```
dcDay    dcTime    dcCount
===========================
  0        10         1
  2        8          2
```

so the result should be:

```
dcDay    dcTime    dcCount
===========================
  0        10         1
  2        8          2
  0        8          1
  1        8          2
```

t1 and t2 are ordered by dcCount, NEWID() and result must ordered by unity(:D),dcCount, NEWID()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, you can accomplish this using Common Table Expressions.

```
WITH CT1(DCDAY,DCTIME,DCCOUNT,SOURCE) AS (
    SELECT DCDAY,DCTIME,DCCOUNT,'T1' AS 'SOURCE'
    FROM T1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DCDAY,DCTIME,DCCOUNT,'T2' AS 'SOURCE'
    FROM T2
)
,CT2(DCDAY,DCTIME,DCCOUNT,[COUNT],[NEWID]) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT DCDAY,DCTIME,DCCOUNT, COUNT(*), NEWID()
    FROM CT1
    GROUP BY DCDAY, DCTIME, DCCOUNT
)
SELECT DCDAY, DCTIME, DCCOUNT 
FROM CT2
ORDER BY [COUNT] DESC, DCCOUNT, [NEWID]
```

You can read more about CTE's here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: Just can say "Thanks"